# How can I capture with fscanf, in C, strings from a file separated by tabulators

Tags: c, tabs, space, capture, scanf

For example the following text (in the file):

18[tab]Robert[tab]Nice to see you again

I want my code capture:
- 18
- Robert
- Nice to see you again

I tried it with fscanf(file,"%s\t",buffer)
but it captured words separated by spaces

Thanks

Comment: What do you want with input like "18[tab][tab]Nice to see you again"?

Answer (score 1):

Use a character set, i.e. `fscanf(file, "%[^\t]\t", buffer);`

The `^` means "all characters except the following".

Remember to check the return value.

Comment: 1)  This will not work when spaces follow the tab as `'\t'` consumes those too.  2) This will save nothing into `buffer`, leaving it as it was if input begins with `'\t'` - yes checkig the return value helps, but this answer does not show what to do when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example you may also want to skip new line characters and other special control characters. You can use `scanf` string conversion `%[` to include wanted characters or to exclude unneeded, for example:

```
/* exclude only '\t' and '\n' */
fscanf(file, "%[^\t\n]", buffer);
/* include only alphanumeric characters and space */
fscanf(file, "%[0-9A-Za-z ]", buffer);
/* include all ASCII printable characters */
fscanf(file, "%[ -~]", buffer);
```

You also should be sure that you have enough space in `buffer`. If you cannot control provided input string length it makes sense to limit the maximum field width using decimal integer number. Before starting parsing the next suitable string it is possible to skip all unwanted symbols. It can be done with opposite conversion pattern and assignment suppression modifier `%*`:

```
char buffer[101]; /* +1 byte for terminating '\0' */

/* Scan loop */
{
    /* Skip all non printable control characters */
    fscanf(file, "%*[^ -~]");

    /* Read up to 100 printable characters so the buffer cannot
     * overflow. It is possible to run the following line in a loop
     * to handle case when one string does not fit into single buffer
     * checking function return value, since it will return 1
     * if at least one wanted character is found */
    fscanf(file, "%100[ -~]", buffer);

    /*
     * If scan would be performed only by the following line it is possible
     * that nothing could be read if the first character is not matching
     * fscanf(file, "%100[ -~]%*[^ -~]", buffer);
     */
}
```

Comment: All these `fscanf()` save nothing into `buffer` leaving it as is, if there is not at least 1 matching `char`.

Comment: @chux Thanks! I updated the answer by improved example. Indeed it is very easy to miss something with tricky operations in `scanf`. That is correct note that the example does not handle case "18[tab][tab]Nice" if the middle substring should be scanned as empty.